# Disable Spring security in Spring boot 1.5.14

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

so when i set the property

```
security.ignored=/**
```

The security is completely disabled

But when i added Method security

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

security.ignored=/** this property wont work

If i set `prePostEnabled = false`, then it works

Is there any property in Spring boot that sets the security disabled

or turn off the Method Security.

I tried

```
security.ignored=/**
spring.security.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
security.basic.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for earlier version than 2.x:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = false)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


}
```

or you can do more customization programmatically by allowing all requests, making patterns, etc.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```